# Qt Android no c++11 support

Tags: android, c++, qt, std

I'm building an Android app in qt and need c++11 support for a 3rd party library.

The app builds fine with my desktop kit (MinGW 5.3.0) but I get multiple errors for my Android kit, like:

```
'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
'strtof' ist not a member of 'std'
etc.
```

My android kit (auto detected):
Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.10.0 for Android armv7)
Compiler: Android GCC (C, arm-4.9)
Compiler: Android GCC (c++, arm-4.9)

NDK Version: r10e

I've already tried to add these flags to the pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -std=c++11
```

The common solution seems to be adding
 
`APP_STL:=c++_static`
 
to your Android.mk file, but as far as I know that doesn't exist when using qt.

These are my CXXFLAGS from the build directory make file:

```
CXXFLAGS      = -D__ANDROID_API__=16 --sysroot=C:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/ -isystem C:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem C:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -std=c++11 -g -g -marm -O0 **-std=gnu++11** -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
```

Comment: You need to set up C++ compiler I guess. Make sure the compiler in 'Compilers' tab is correct (or set it manually). Also make sure correct one is chosen in the kit.

Comment: Any suggestions on what the correct compiler is? I've got "Android GCC" for the Android kit and "MinGW 5.3.0" for the desktop kit.

Seems to me like I can't change the compiler, if I still want to deploy to Android.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` , `#include <stdlib.h>` should work

Comment: I've updated my question since the first version was not precise - sry, didn't know better at the time. 

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?